# Google Maps javascript API custom draggable marker using PNG not visible in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This Google Maps Javascript API V3 code works properly in every other browser than Safari. In Safari the draggable PNG icon is invisible.

```
var image="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon20.png";

var locationmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Search Location',
    optimized: false,
    icon: image,
    draggable:true
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are loading the PNG file over HTTP which causes CORS issue. Try to load it over HTTPS. Change the PNG file URL to `https://` instead of `http://`:

```
https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon20.png
```

Comment: The icon PNG could also be hosted locally assuming the hosting site is reached via an https: URL.